# SqlConnection timing out instantly

Tags: c#, ado.net, connection-timeout

Writing a very simple tool to ping SQL servers and make sure that a bunch of connection strings can be accessed, I came across a very strange problem: while iterating a couple dozens of connection strings, the first half a dozen timed out after approximately however many seconds I specified (11 in this particular case) and logged corresponding attempt and exception current wall times, but then all of a sudden about a dozen of them timed out instantaneously, and then normal timeouts resumed.

This is running on a machine, which does not have any network access to the one IP used in all of the connection strings to be tested. In the log it looks like this:

```
2018-04-06 15:59:40     Connection name: 
2018-04-06 15:59:40     SQL Error:Connection Timeout Expired.  Th
or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration s
2018-04-06 15:59:40     Connection name: 
2018-04-06 15:59:40     SQL Error:Connection Timeout Expired.  Th
or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration s
2018-04-06 15:59:40     Connection name: 
2018-04-06 15:59:40     SQL Error:Connection Timeout Expired.  Th
or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration s
2018-04-06 15:59:40     Connection name: 
2018-04-06 15:59:40     SQL Error:Connection Timeout Expired.  Th
or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration s
2018-04-06 15:59:40     Connection name: 
2018-04-06 15:59:40     SQL Error:Connection Timeout Expired.  Th
or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration s
2018-04-06 15:59:40     Connection name: 
2018-04-06 15:59:40     SQL Error:Connection Timeout Expired.  Th
or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration s
2018-04-06 15:59:40     Connection name: 
2018-04-06 15:59:40     SQL Error:Connection Timeout Expired.  Th
or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration s
2018-04-06 15:59:40     Connection name: 
2018-04-06 15:59:40     SQL Error:Connection Timeout Expired.  Th
or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration s
2018-04-06 15:59:40     Connection name: 
2018-04-06 15:59:40     SQL Error:Connection Timeout Expired.  Th
or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration s
2018-04-06 15:59:40     Connection name: 
2018-04-06 15:59:40     SQL Error:Connection Timeout Expired.  Th
or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration s
2018-04-06 15:59:40     Connection name: 
2018-04-06 15:59:54     SQL Error:Connection Timeout Expired.  Th
or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration s
2018-04-06 15:59:54     Connection name: 
2018-04-06 15:59:54     SQL Error:Connection Timeout Expired.  Th
or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration s
2018-04-06 15:59:54     Connection name: 
2018-04-06 16:00:08     SQL Error:Connection Timeout Expired.  Th
or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration s
2018-04-06 16:00:08     Connection name: 
2018-04-06 16:00:22     SQL Error:Connection Timeout Expired.  Th
or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration s
2018-04-06 16:00:22     Connection name: 
2018-04-06 16:00:35     SQL Error:Connection Timeout Expired.  Th
or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration s
2018-04-06 16:00:35     Connection name: 
2018-04-06 16:00:49     SQL Error:Connection Timeout Expired.  Th
or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration s
```

See how after a bunch of instant timeouts the last entry logged at 15:59:40 times out at 15:59:54 which is normal, then another connection times out instantly, and everything after 16:00:08 times out normally again.

The code looks to me perfectly textbook innocent:

```
foreach (ConnectionStringSettings cs in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
{
    if (cs.Name.Equals("LocalSqlServer") && !args.Contains("NoSkipLocal", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) continue;

    SqlConnectionStringBuilder b = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(cs.ConnectionString)
    {
        ConnectTimeout = timeout == 0 ? 10 : timeout
    };

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(b.ConnectionString);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        LogToConsole("Connection success", ConsoleColor.Green);
    }
    catch (SqlException sex)
    {
        LogToConsole("SQL Error:" + sex.Message, ConsoleColor.Red);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogToConsole("Error:" + ex.Message, ConsoleColor.Red);
    }

static void LogToConsole(string message, ConsoleColor color = ConsoleColor.Gray)
{
    ConsoleColor fgColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
    Console.ForegroundColor = color;
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "\t" + message);
    Console.ForegroundColor = fgColor;
}
```

Did anyone else experience instant timeouts with the ADO.NET SqlConnection object? I was expecting that a connection failure might very well be instant, but at least the message should have been different. But it was exactly the same as when ~14 seconds elapsed.

Comment: I'm wondering if the problem is you have exhausted the connection pool - you are opening connections, but never closing them again...Perhaps you should put your `SqlConnection conn` in a `using` block? Not sure if it would manifest in exactly this way, but would explain the weird behaviour if it does. Regardless - you will definitely have problems with this code as the number of connections increases, so worth fixing anyway.

Comment: Are you able to manually connect to the servers that instantly timeout?  The timeout is for how long it should wait to give up.  If it knows the connection not available prior to the timeout period it’s able to abort quicker.

Comment: The logs look like they may have been cut off. Is it possible to see the rest of each log line?

Comment: I Agree with @RB - I think once you will dispose your connection object (simply add a `finally` clause to your existing `try...catch` with `conn?.Dispose()`) the problem will go away.

Comment: None of that makes any difference whatsoever, this is why I did not bother. And no, the log is truncated on purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `Pooling = false` to the connection string builder instantiation fixed the issue. Now each connection waits specified number of seconds before throwing an exception.

It is not enough to dispose of a `SqlConnection` while connection pooling is on, the ADO.NET pool still holds an entry to a particular DB and stores the last error state, so when the next connection object is instantiated with the connection string pointing at the same, the timeout connecting is returned instantaneously.

In my particular case that is a good behaviour, as it saves me time testing connection strings, but in real world it may represent a nasty side effect.